# Обрезать лишний текст в параграфе, внутри блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой задачей: нужно, чтобы внутри блока была картинка и текст в параграфе, если текста слишком много, он должен быть обрезан (символов "..." вполне хватит).

Пробую `text-overflow: ellipsis` но безрезультатно, подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить это работать.

Вот пример кода:

```html
<div style="margin: 50px; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;">
     <p>
      Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
     </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно при помощи jquery, но можно и на css.

```js
$("p").text(function(i, text) {

  if (text.length >= 50) {
    text = text.substring(0, 50);
    var lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");       // позиция последнего пробела
    text = text.substring(0, lastIndex) + '...'; // обрезаем до последнего слова
  }
  
  $(this).text(text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin: 50px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid black;">
    <p>
        Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
         test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
         test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
         test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
         test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
</div>
```

**Без количества символов:**

```js
(function($) {
        var truncate = function(el) {
            var text = el.text(),
                height = el.height(),
                clone = el.clone();

       clone.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                visibility: 'hidden',
                height: 'auto'
            });
            el.after(clone);

            var l = text.length - 1;
            for (; l >= 0 && clone.height() > height; --l) {
                clone.text(text.substring(0, l) + '...');
            }

            el.text(clone.text());
            clone.remove();
        };

        $.fn.truncateText = function() {
            return this.each(function () {
                truncate($(this));
            });
        };
        
         $('div').truncateText();
    }(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div style="margin: 50px; width: 100px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid black;">
      <p>
        Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        test test test test test test test test test test
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Решение хорошее, но, как я понял, требует хотя бы приблизительного знания того, сколько символов должен быть текст для данной высоты. Если можно ограничиться только знанием высоты текста и чистым css, без js'а, было бы очень здорово! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Mark Khromov сделал, теперь все зависит от высоты блока, а не количества символов))

Comment: Ваше решение лучшее, для моей задачи, помечаю ответ как верный! Спасибо за помощь!!!

Answer (score 2):

Если Вем принципально решение на чистом CSS-е обратите внимание на [решение из статьи](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.d1 {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста много много текста 
</div>
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Но спасибо, в любом случае, за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Как пример если на CSS и если свойство  text-overflow: ellipsis;  - не ставит точки можно вот так:

```css
 
div{
   margin: 50px; 
   width: 100px; 
   height: 300px; 
   border: 2px solid black;  
   overflow: hidden;
    /*-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
    /*text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
    position: relative; 
 }
 div:after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>
     Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
       test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
   </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Неплохое решение! Спасибо!